# Store values in nested list to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Initial dataframe

```
            Media_ID            Post Number
0   2064531743772077759             1
1   2172781699280526966             2
2   2161918718997085520             3
3   2199646075933418046             4
4   1525499382425703584             5
```

The media ID inputted into:
`instagram.get_media_comments_by_id(2064531743772077759,100)`
will return 100 comments from the post with media id: `2064531743772077759`.
The result of 10 items in a loop is as follows:

```
[{'comment0': {'next_page': None,
   'comments': [<igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c09e389e8>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c09e38630>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c09e38f98>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c09eba0f0>]}},
 {'comment1': {'next_page': None,
   'comments': [<igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c09eba278>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c09eba1d0>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c09eba160>,
...
{'comment9': {'next_page': None,
   'comments': [<igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c0a1ba7b8>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c0a1ba860>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c0a1ba5c0>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c0a1ba630>,
    <igramscraper.model.comment.Comment at 0x27c0a1f2860>]}}]
```

I need to get the `comment0`,`comment1`,`comment2`,...`comment9` out of the list and make them dict.

Then, I can use the following code to make a data frame:

```
for i,_ in enumerate(df['link'], 1):
    df2pi = pd.DataFrame( [{'Comments':comment.text} for comment in locals()[f"comment{i}"]['comments'] ] )
    df2pi['Date']=df['date'][i-1]
```

Expected Output:
[image: Expected Comments Output]

Comment: please see the revised question. I just need the comment0, comment1, ... out of the list and make each of them a separate variable @deadshot

Comment: but commecnts is list of objects?

Comment: i am not exactly sure how to check that?

Comment: if you create dataframe with above data you get list of comment objects for each row

Comment: previously, I didn't use the loop. So, I did the following: `comment0 = instagram.get_media_comment_by_id(code,100)`. `comment0` is a DICT. Then, I use the enumerate code to create a dataframe. Now I try to use a loop, but the `comment0` is stuck within a list.

Comment: update your post with sample input and expected output

Comment: are the comments serial?

Comment: yes they are, comment0, comment1, comment2, comment3... @SeyiDaniel

Comment: please have a look at the revised edit @deadshot